# SQL statement error in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to execute the SQL statment below  in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
CREATE TABLE Nrom1Tab ( Sig TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   DocSubject TEXT,  
   DocClassification TEXT,  
   DepName VARCHAR, 
   OrgName TEXT,  
   FromInf  TEXT,   
   ToInf TEXT,    
   DateInf TEXT, 
   NoteInf TEXT );
```

It shows this error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the error message is, however

1. `TEXT` is not a valid data type in Oracle.
2. `VARCHAR` is a valid data type but you would need to specify the length (i.e. `VARCHAR(10)`) would allow up to 10 bytes of storage (assuming a default `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` of `BYTE`).  It would generally be preferred to use the `VARCHAR2` data type rather than `VARCHAR` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error complaining about missing a left parenthesis, is angry that VARCHAR doesn't have a length defined.  The error references column 113, which would be where the left parenthesis *should* be, the 114th character on that line.

Justin also correctly points out TEXT is not a valid datatype.  While I don't think that is causing the error you're seeing, it'll be an error very soon :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to give VARCHAR an amount like VARCHAR(50).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Nrom1Tab 
( 
    Sig TEXT PRIMARY KEY, DocSubject TEXT,  DocClassification TEXT,  
    DepName VARCHAR(100), -- Missing LENGTH
    OrgName TEXT,  FromInf  TEXT,   ToInf TEXT,   DateInf TEXT, NoteInf TEXT );
```